# Surround all words with spans in php

Tags: php, regex

Given an HTML string like this one:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetuer adipiscing</a>
elit, <strong>tincidunt</strong> ut volutpat.
```

How do I surround all the words with `<span>` elements, so it becomes:

```
<span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span>
<span>amet,</span> <a href="#"><span>consectetuer</span> <span>adipiscing</span></a>
<span>elit,</span> <strong><span>tincidunt</span></strong> <span>ut</span>
<span>volutpat.</span>
```

Comment: Is it the best idea to do this in PHP? You might want to do it in Javascript, where you have easier access to the DOM.

Comment: you can try 
str_replace(" ", "<span>", $yourstring)
but you have to add more logic.
replce evry odd space with <span> and even one with </span>
also you have to skip this for html elements

Comment: I've tried https://gist.github.com/3314475  obviously it didn't work, that's why I'm asking

Comment: The processing is done server-side and I store it in the database, that's why I tagged it with PHP

Comment: @arxanas, You have just as easy access to the DOM in PHP as you do in JavaScript.  Many DOM classes are available.

Comment: @Brad PHP won't account for malformed input as well as the  browser.

Comment: @arxanas, Prove it.  DOMDocument works with malformed HTML just fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simpler approach

```
preg_replace('([a-zA-Z.,!?0-9]+(?![^<]*>))', '<span>$0</span>', '{{your data}}');
```

It surrounds with `<span>` all words from your vocabulary `[a-zA-Z.,!?0-9]+` except words in `<brackets>`.
Now it seems to be easy to change your vocabulary if needed, e.g. if you don't want single punctuation to became surrounded, etc.

Comment: Didn't get it matters. However there is a simpler regex.

Comment: I realized non-ASCII characters don't get picked in this regex. My solution in the end was to wrap non-space characters all together, so `preg_replace('/(<[\s\S]*?>)|([^\s-\<]+)/',"$1<span>$2</span>", $string);`

Comment: So if you want alphabet `[^\s-\<]+`, use this alphabet in my final regex - `([^\s-\<>]+(?![^<]*>))`. [Test link](http://goo.gl/zCeeV)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this, think this is what you are looking for:

```
$result = preg_replace("/(<[^>]+>)?\\w*/us", "<span>$0</span>", $searchText);
```

This is the input

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetuer adipiscing</a>elit, <strong>tincidunt</strong> ut volutpat.
```

And this is the output

```
<span>Lorem</span> <span>ipsum</span> <span>dolor</span> <span>sit</span> <span>amet</span>, <span><a href="#">consectetuer</span> <span>adipiscing</span><span></a></span><span>elit</span>, <span><strong>tincidunt</span><span></strong></span> <span>ut</span> <span>volutpat</span>.
```

Comment: this wraps even the html tags in <span> tag for example the </a>.. nice try though

Comment: The `s` pattern modifier serves no purpose because there is no `.` (any character metacharacter) in the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

If @daftcoder's solution works for you that's great, but it does fail if you have entities (&lt; etc) in your code. I couldn't find any other cases where it failed.

If that matters, you can use DOM manipulation in PHP. I know this is way more complicated, but it should work in more cases than the simple regex.

The walk and doReplace functions are converted from JS to PHP from the answer to another question. ( [Surrounding individual words inside HTML text with SPAN tags?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059682/surrounding-individual-words-inside-html-text-with-span-tags) )

```
<?php

echo wrap_words('span', 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, <a href="#">consectetuer adipiscing</a> elit, <strong>tincidunt</strong> ut volutpat.');

function wrap_words($tag, $text) {
    $document = new DOMDocument();
    $fragment = $document->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXml($text);
    walk($tag, $fragment);
    $html = $document->saveHtml($fragment);
    // using saveHTML with a documentFragment can leave an invalid "<>"
    // at the beginning of the string - remove it
    return preg_replace('/^<>/', '', $html);
}

function walk($tag, $root)
{
    if ($root->nodeType == XML_TEXT_NODE)
    {
        doReplace($tag, $root);
        return;
    }
    $children = $root->childNodes;
    for ($i = $children->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        walk($tag, $children->item($i));
    }
}

function doReplace($tag, $text)
{
    $fragment = $text->ownerDocument->createDocumentFragment();
    $fragment->appendXML(preg_replace('/\S+/', "<{$tag}>\$0</{$tag}>", $text->nodeValue));
    $parent = $text->parentNode;
    $children = $fragment->childNodes;
    for ($i = $children->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--)
    {
        $parent->insertBefore($children->item($i), $text->nextSibling);
    }
    $parent->removeChild($text);
}
```