# How to wrap text with HTML tags but exclude text inside certain HTML tags

Tags: javascript

I'm creating some functions to highlight words on a page. This will be done wrapping span tags around the given words. I've completed this task but will explain a little more.

The way the code works is to take the innerHTML when the page first loads, and store this in memory (so I have a copy of the original content).

I then take a copy of the innerHTML (called copyInnerHtml) - I then find the search words on copyInnerHtml, and wrap them with `<span id="find-iteration">` (where iteration is a unique number, such as find-0, find-1, find-2 etc) tags and replace the contents of the page with copyInnerHtml. Then, when the user re-hits the search button, I first revert the page back to the original innerHTML content, and then continue as above. This works well.

How to do I find text (website copy) only words and note words used as values in HTML elements/attributes.

Example, Consider the following code

```
 <div class="search">This is the search box</div>
```

Now, I want to perform a search for the word "**search**". The issue is, it will find it twice.

Without using regular expressions, and only using JavaScript (no jQuery please), how can I detect if the string is part of the HTML tag or not?

This **[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/n008Lq3j/1/)** should make things clearer in regards to what I've done

Now, you'll hopefully note the following line in the fiddle

```
<p class="changeMe">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Please update this to

```
<p class="find">&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>
```

And you will see the code breaks. This is what I mean, when I search for a word (in the case of the JSFIDDLE, the word 'find') then I only want to search by website copy.

Comment: Create DOM element, set HTML, then get it's TEXT (not html, will be "this is the search box"), and perform search on it.

Comment: You want to retrieve the `<div>` element based on a fragment of its text, or you want to find the string `"search"` in the text-content but not in the attribute-values?

Comment: The question is still unclear. Do you want to get a `true` or `false` when checking if the text inside the div contains the class attribute?

Comment: You've nothing to apologise for, I was just curious as to what you wanted - and clarification generally helps get better answers. So: you want to find specific search terms, in the text of the document and then wrap those found-strings with a `<span>`? Incidentally, if you use an `id` of `'find-iteration'` then *all* found strings will have the same `id`, which would immediately invalidate the page, so I'd suggest using a class-name, or a custom `data-*` attribute instead.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Surrounding individual words inside HTML text with SPAN tags?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5059682/surrounding-individual-words-inside-html-text-with-span-tags)

Comment: @DavidThomas, `find-iteration` will actually be find-0, find-1, find-2 etc. As I said, the thing works but it's possible the code will find words which exist in the HTML tags, which I don't want to be the case. The solution in my head is, when I find a words position using indexof, I start looping backwards each prior character. If I find a `>` then I know i'm not in a tag, if I find an `<` the I'm inside a tag (although I know this has other issues)

Comment: @RGraham, no, that is asking for any word to be wrapped, mine isn't about how to do the wrapping, I know that bit, It's about only wrapping certain text

Comment: I think the duplicate is sufficiently complete that you can add a simple `if(~text.indexOf("search"))` statement inside the `doReplace`. I'm not saying that answers your question to the letter, but if you put a little bit of effort in, it will be the same answer as anything you'll get here. For example - http://jsfiddle.net/z8ortfuv/

Comment: @RGraham, my question is how to wrap text agreed **when** that text isn't inside an HTML tag... Are you still saying you feel it is a dupe, if so I'll give it more time but I generally don't see it myself. Note, the fiddle I added my help add clarity?

Comment: @DavidThomas, I've added a fiddle

Comment: @RGraham, thanks for the fiddle, I now understand why you feel it's a dupe. It is but sadly the dupe isn't an answer with my current approach (so guess that still classes it as a dupe)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as you know, you have to process the whole (or part of) the DOM.
While doing this, you have to cross-check each tagName against a blacklist of tags you do not want to process.

Here is a small example of how this might be done in vanilla javascript:

```
var excludeElements = ['script', 'style', 'a', 'form', 'iframe', 'canvas'];

var markText = function(textToHighlight) {

    walk(document.body, textToHighlight, function(node, match, offset) {
        var abbrevNode = document.createElement("span");
        abbrevNode.appendChild(document.createTextNode(textToHighlight));
        abbrevNode.className="someClass";
    });

}

var walk = function(node, textToHighlight, callback) { 


    var child = node.firstChild;

    while (child) {
        switch (child.nodeType) {
        case 1:
            if (excludeElements.indexOf(child.tagName.toLowerCase()) > -1)
                break;
            walk(child, textToHighlight, callback);
            break;
        case 3:
            var bk = 0;
            child.data.replace(textToHighlight, function(all) {
                var args = [].slice.call(arguments),
                    offset = args[args.length - 2],
                    newTextNode = child.splitText(offset+bk), tag;
                bk -= child.data.length + all.length;

                newTextNode.data = newTextNode.data.substr(all.length);
                tag = callback.apply(window, [child].concat(args));
                child.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, newTextNode);
                child = newTextNode;
            });
            break;
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }

    return node;
};
```